# Remove a port from a VLAN (HP ProCurve)

Tags: hp-procurve

I'm not too familiar with switches but I want to remove port 6 from the following 'VLAN 12' I've tried searching for an easy explanation to no avail - How do I do this please?

```
Port Information Mode     Unknown VLAN Status
---------------- -------- ------------ ----------
5                Untagged Learn        Up
6                Tagged   Learn        Up
8                Untagged Learn        Up
18               Untagged Learn        Down
22               Untagged Learn        Up
26               Tagged   Learn        Up
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
config
vlan 12
no tagged 6
exit
exit
wr mem
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
config
no vlan 12 tagged 6
exit
```